# Quotients of Two-sided and One-sided Ideals

Tags: ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals, division-algebras, module-isomorphism

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a central simple algebra over an algebraic number field $K$, and $\mathcal{O}$ be a maximal $\mathcal{O}_K$-order in $\mathcal{A}$. Let $I$ be a maximal integral left-ideal of $\mathcal{O}$. Then there is a unique associated two-sided prime ideal of $\mathcal{O}$, say $\mathfrak{P}$, such that $\mathfrak{P}\subset I\subset\mathcal{O}$. Let $q\in\mathbb{Z}$ be a rational prime. My question is the following: are $\mathfrak{P}/q\mathfrak{P}$ and $I/qI$ isomorphic?

I know that the natural inclusion $\mathfrak{P}\hookrightarrow I$ induces an injection $\mathfrak{P}/q\mathfrak{P}\hookrightarrow I/qI$; I also know how to find the absolute norm of $\mathfrak{P}/q\mathfrak{P}$, which gives the cardinality of $|\mathfrak{P}/q\mathfrak{P}|$. However, I don't know how to find the cardinality of $I/qI$. In addition, I am also struggling to prove whether the map is surjective.

Comment: An algebra over what?

Comment: Sorry! An algebra over a field, and the order is an order over the ring of integers of the field.

Comment: What is the ring of integers of a field?

Comment: In the case where the field is an algebraic number field, the ring of integers makes sense - sorry for not specifying properly.

Comment: One idea is to show $I/qI$ injects into $\mathcal{O}/q\mathcal{O}$, and $\mathcal{O}/q\mathcal{O}$ injects into $\mathfrak{P}/q\mathfrak{P}$. Then, since $\mathcal{O}/q\mathcal{O}$ is finite, and given that there is an injection in the other direction, we would be done. I'm struggling to show the kernel of the map $I\rightarrow \mathcal{O}/q\mathcal{O}$ induced by the inclusion has the correct kernel, however!

Comment: My suggestion is to try to reduce it to a local problem, where the theory of CSAs is simpler.  (It should just reduce to checking the local problem at $q$.)

Comment: Is this correct: consider $\mathcal{O}$ over the completion of $\mathcal{O}_K$ at $q$, denoted $\mathcal{O}_q$. Since $\mathcal{O}$ is a maximal order, $\mathcal{O}_q$ is maximal too. In this ring every one-sided ideal is two-sided, and a power of the unique prime ideal of $\mathcal{O}_q$, denoted $\hat{\mathfrak{P}}$. If $q$ is the rational prime inside $\mathfrak{P}$, we obtain that $\mathfrak{P}/q\mathfrak{P}$ completes to $\hat{\mathfrak{P}}/q\hat{\mathfrak{P}}$, and that $\hat{I/qI} = \hat{I}/q\hat{I} = \hat{\mathfrak{P}}^n/q\hat{\mathfrak{P}}^n$, for some $n$, which are isomorphic.

Comment: Is isomorphism at the completion sufficient to demonstrate isomorphism in the original case? And a couple of follow up questions: firstly, as far as I can tell, the above doesn't use maximality of $I$; does the result hold for any one-sided ideal containing $\mathfrak{P}$? and secondly, what about if $q$ is not contained in $\mathfrak{P}$?